# How to test login page with multiple usernames(present in excel) using selenium web driver c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, selenium, webdriver

By using selenium web driver c#. How to test login page with different usernames and password(present in excel sheet),how to connect and import the data present in excel to the login page automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Use datadriven testing : Testing the same scenarios with multiple sets of data.[Data Driven Testing in selenium with C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jawedmd/data-driven-testing-using-selenium-webdriver-in-C-Sharp/)